# How would you go about creating a algorithm that should generate a shakespearean sonnet on any given theme

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I need to create an algorithm that is going to create a shakespearean sonnet for a specific theme. This theme should be generated out of twitter tweets that have some hashtag.

My current idea goes like

**While training:**

- break up sonnets and other kinds of poems into words (or charachters, have not decided yet)
- extract key words from sonnet using tf/idf
- convert key words into a vector that will represent a theme using doc2vec
- use this words and a theme vector as an input in lstm network to generate a sonnet by predicting next word (charachter) on a particular theme but without a sonnet structure
- create a discriminator lstm network with the same input but trained only on sonnets main function of which is going to be to find how much does this poem looks like a sonnet
- combine generator and discriminator networks into a GAN

**While generating**

- find some amount of tweets with this hashtag
- extract keywords from this tweets using tf/idf
- convert this key words into one vector using doc2vec
- generate a sonnet with a trained model usin this parameters

I am only a beginner in machine learning, so I would like to hear opinions of more experienced data scientist, is this algorithm going to work and what can be improved?

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds like a broad question.  Asking how to approach an entire project might be too broad for this site.  In any case, unless someone happens to have tried to do exactly this before, there might be no known answer.  The standard approach to this sort of thing is (a) read the literature to see if you can find anyone who has solved this problem or a similar one; (b) come up with something reasonable and try it, and iterate.  You've come up with a reasonable idea, and the only way to find out how well it will work is probably to implement and see.

Comment: Perhaps a more suitable use of this site will be to try the approach you listed, and if you get stuck somewhere specific, ask about that.  That said, here's my personal opinion: this sounds like a very challenging project for a beginner at machine learning.  I wouldn't recommend this as a starter project -- I'd suggest starting with something narrower.